# Is it possible to use AWUS036H as bridged adapter in VirtualBox on OS X host that does not recognize the card?

Tags: macos, networking, virtualbox

I want to use my Alfa AWUS036H as a bridged adapter in VirtualBox. The problem is that my host OS is Mac OS X 1.18 and there are no drivers for the card available, so I cannot tell VirtualBox what the name of the bridge adapter should be.

Is it possible to connect VirtualBox to the AWUS036H without it being actually installed on my host OS? Maybe via some other way? I want to exchange network packets directly via this card, not via NAT.

Comment: You shouldn't have to have drivers for the host operating system to attached a usb device to a virtualbox virtual machine.

Comment: I can attach the USB but I want the card to be a bridged adapter and it seems like I need drivers for that

Comment: You will be unable to use this device as a bridge adapter if the host operating system does not support said device.